# How can I paint on 3D object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I know about `Terrain`, but I can't rotate `Terrain`for 90 degrees. So I need to paint on cube to different textures / materials *with brush* like on `Terrain`. Is it possible? Unity 5.6.4p2.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can paint on the textures using `Texture2D.SetPixel()`  (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixel.html)

Comment: Only with script?

Comment: @Eloren, https://unity3d.com/unity/features/worldbuilding/polybrush 
But it only works in "edit" mode, not runtime.

Comment: I don't have polybrush. Also will it work inside the game apk?

Comment: @Eloren, Nope. The polybrush works only in the editor, but generated meshes may be included to the Android build. So, if you want to paint on textures in runtime, use a script based on Texture2D.SetPixel(), but if you want to paint on some meshes in editor, try the Polybrush tool. Anyway, this tool have some limitations (see manual).